# Why this notification is not shown on a 2.3.6 device?

Tags: android, notifications

I have got this simple code that issues a Notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this)
    .setSmallIcon(
            R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Error deactivating Tracker")
            .setContentText("Unable to send deactivation SMS");

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

The notifications shows correctly on a 4.4.2 device, but it does not show on a 2.3.6 device.

I am using the `NotificationCompat` so I suppose it should show.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Apparently it wants a PendingIntent in any case,

so I added it:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(),      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this)
    .setSmallIcon(
            R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Error deactivating Tracker")
            .setContentText("Unable to send deactivation SMS")
            .setContentIntent(pi).setTicker("Error deactivating Tracker");

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```